# Kendo MVC Grid define columns when Model is Dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I want to know how to define columns when I pass a dictionary to a Kendo MVC Grid as its model like in this code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Dictionary<string, string>>()
                .Name("tbl")            
                    .Sortable()
                    .Columns(c =>
                    {
                        c.Bound(e => e.Keys.ElementAt(0));
                        c.Bound(e => e.Keys.ElementAt(1));
                    })
                .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetReporting", "Report"))
                )
```

But I encounter the following error:

**Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: Bound columns require a field or property access expression.

I don't know how to define columns in this code

Answer (score -1):

Try to bound not an expression, but a plain string:

```
 .Columns(c =>
                {
                   foreach(string key in e.Keys)
                   {
                       c.Bound(key);
                   }
                })
```